# insert conditions with variable to select String only if the variable is not null

Tags: java

I need to write a function that would return a 'select' String sentence.

in the sentence i want to combine conditions only if the variables are not null.

```
public String getFilterCondition(Group group) {


    String sendMail= group.getEmail();
    String phone= group.getPhone();
    String gender= group.getGender();

    return "select * from member where sendMail='"+sendMail+"' and phone='"+phone+"' and gender='"+gender+"'" ;

}
```

the conditions with the variables will be include in the statement only if they are not null.

how can i do that in short way?

thanks!

Comment: With just an if statement, you can check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public String getFilterCondition(Group group) {

    String sendMail = group.getEmail();
    String phone = group.getPhone();
    String gender = group.getGender();
    String concat = "where ";

    String query = "select * from member ";
    if (sendMail != null) {
        query += concat + "sendMail='" + sendMail + "' ";
        concat = "and ";
    }
    if (phone != null) {
        query += concat + "phone='" + phone + "'";
        concat = "and ";
    }
    if (gender != null) {
        query += concat + "gender='" + gender + "'";
    }

    return query;

}
```

Comment: Great! this is the best

Comment: I'm glad it was useful, please if you consider this as the correct answer, mark as it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.

```
public String getFilterCondition(Group group) {

    String sendMail= group.getEmail();
    String phone= group.getPhone();
    String gender= group.getGender();

    String returnValue = "select * from member "; 
    boolean needWhereClause = true;
    if ((sendMail != null) && ! sendMail.equals("")) {
        returnValue = returnValue + (needWhereClause ? "where " : "and ");
        needWhereClause = false; 
        returnValue = returnValue + "sendMail = '" + sendMail + "' ";
    } 
    if ((phone != null) && ! phone.equals("")) {
        returnValue = returnValue + (needWhereClause ? "where " : "and ");
        needWhereClause = false; 
        returnValue = returnValue + "phone = '" + phone + "' ";
    } 
    if ((gender != null) && ! gender.equals("")) {
        returnValue = returnValue + (needWhereClause ? "where " : "and ");
        needWhereClause = false; 
        returnValue = returnValue + "gender = '" + gender + "' ";
    } 
    return  returnValue;
}
```

Comment: According to his requirements, you should return null if any of them is null. Rest he will check there if the string is null or not; he will proceed then.

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest way (only if your columns are varchars) is to do it like this:

```
return "select * from member where sendMail like " + (sendMail != null ? "'" + sendMail + "'" : "'%'") + " and ...";
```

Comment: which would be bad. if sendMail would be null, the sendMail should not be in the where clause at all

Comment: Well, define 'bad'. If sendMail would be null then my query will work as it should. The question is about the shortest way of doing that so I think my solution is shorter than creating three different if statements and checking there is 'and' operator should be appended or not.

Comment: "bad' as in: doesn't follow the requirements. besides, just because the parameter you get is null, doesn't mean the value in the db is null.

Comment: I think it is really the only option. since I have a lot of variables  i cannot use if to each one.

Comment: user: yes, it is an option, but the entire where part for that variable should depend on the if, not just the value you pass as parameter